# Generate Valid hdiv url in controller

Tags: spring-security, hdiv

i have successfully configured Spring Boot 2.0.4 to use spring-security with HDIV.
I decided to use jquery datatable as table rendering technology.
Here come the problem...
For each row of my datatable i'd like to create a detail link signed with _HDIV_STATE_ parameter how can i generate a valid link while iterating my item list in a controller?

A generic Controller:

```
@Controller
public class ItemController {

   ....

   @GetMapping(value = "/test")
   public @ResponseBody test() {
      List<Item> items = service.getList();
      items.foreach(item -> {
         item.setDetailUrl(HDIV_GENERATED_URL);
      })
    }

   ...

  }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inject the LinkUrlProcessor class in the controller.

```
@autowired
LinkUrlProcessor linkUrlProcessor;
```

And invoke `processUrl` method.

```
String processedUrl linkUrlProcessor.processUrl(request, originalUrl);
```

The `processedUrl` will contain the `_HDIV_STATE_` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this solution work fine only with ulrs with pathvariable.

```
@Autowired
ServletContext context;

public @ResponseBody String test() {
  int id = 1;
  LinukUrlProcessor lup = HDIVUtil.getLinkUrlProcessor(context);
  RequestContextHolder rch =HDIVUtil.getRequestContext(context);
  //This works perfectly
  String processedWithPath = lup.processUrl(rch, "/test" + id);
  //This produce a _HVID_STATE_ but query param always 0
  String processedWithQuery = lup.processUrl(rch, "/test?id=" + id);
  return ....
}
```

Any further help generating valid url with query parameters?

Comment: The query param value is always 0 because 'confidentiality feature is activated. The link with param value= 0 should work perfectly. If you want to see the real value, deactivate confidentiality. https://hdivsecurity.com/docs/installation/library-setup/#confidentiality